# Injective hull commutes with Hom

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Notation: $E_R(M)$ is the injective hull of $M$.

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$, and $M$ an $R$-module. Then $$\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, E_R(M)) \cong E_{R/I}(\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M))$$ as $R/I$-modules.

I'm not sure how to approach this. Can anyone give me some hints?

I tried writing $E(M)$ as a direct sum of irreducible injective modules, so $E(M) = \bigoplus E(R/\mathfrak{p_i})$. That they are isomorphic as $R/I$-modules is especially tripping me up since most things give $R$-module isomorphisms.

Comment: I have an answer with additional assumption: IM = 0